# Suftesi font in book class

Tags: fonts, texlive, books

How can i have the series of font of [suftesi](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/suftesi/suftesi-doc.pdf) in a normal book class of LaTeX ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `suftesi` class is based on `book` class, so getting what you ask is not difficult. As you can read from the manual, this class uses the `palatino` font as default, the `iwona` font as sans serif, and, if you look to the code of the class, the `beramono` font for the monospaced font. This code should be ok:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled=0.8]{beramono}
\linespread{1.05}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwona}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

{\sffamily \lipsum[1]}

{\ttfamily \lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

The `\linespread` command is used to add (few) space between lines.